# java - Hello World servlet has no output

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I haven't changed anything in index.jsp and web.xml.
The ouput has to be Hello World but there isn't any.

Here is the code of MyServlet.java:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
    printWriter.println("Hello World");
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

}}
```

Comment: You have to make a request to the server, and then `Hello World` will be in the response body. Were you looking at the console instead?

Comment: Nope. I'm an absolute beginner in Java EE. Could you show me how to make a request?

Comment: Generally you would just visit `http://localhost:8080` in your browser. Maybe post a link to the Hello World tutorial you are following to get more specific help.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did. Here is the result: https://pp.userapi.com/c638518/v638518628/426ba/ujf209LEwGc.jpg

Comment: here, check here https://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need to call name which you mapped in web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.HelloWorld
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> // this is optional
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
```

then you can access like http://localhost:8080/hello

If you are using below servlet 3.0 you need have mapping of your servlet as follows:

if you are using servlet 3.0 (annotation based) then it should be as follows:

@WebServlet("/hello")

```
   public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

   @Override

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException 
   {
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

        writer.println("<p>Hello World!</p>");
```

}
}

then you can access like http://localhost:8080/hello